# Как поправить пути в css файле?

Tags: webpack

Как поправить пути в css файле?
Внутри плагина MiniCssExtractPlugin выставляю, чтоб css был внутри папки css. Внутри dist она создается, но пути до картинки и шрифта не подстроились. Как поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавлять publicPath для внутри лоадера, то пути создаются в виде "D:\Projects\webpack-test\dist/1.jpg", что тоже некорректно

```html
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const isProd = !isDev;

const PATHS = {
  dist: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
};

const optimization = () => {
  const config = {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
    },
  };

  if (isProd) {
    config.minimizer = [new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()];
  }

  return config;
};

const filename = (ext, section = "") =>
  isDev ? `${section}[name].${ext}` : `${section}[name].[hash].${ext}`;

const cssLoaders = (extra) => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        hmr: isDev,
        reloadAll: true,
        //publicPath: PATHS.dist,
      },
    },
    "css-loader",
  ];

  if (extra) {
    loaders.push(extra);
  }

  return loaders;
};

const babelLoaders = (preset) => {
  const options = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
  };

  if (preset) {
    options.presets.push(preset);
  }

  return options;
};

module.exports = {
  context: PATHS.src,
  watch: false,
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    main: ["@babel/polyfill", "./scripts/index.jsx"],
    analytics: "./scripts/analytics.js",
  },
  output: {
    //filename: "scripts/[name].js",
    filename: filename("js"),
    path: PATHS.dist,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      "@": PATHS.src,
    },
  },
  optimization: optimization(),
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: isProd,
    port: 9000,
    hot: isDev,
  },
  devtool: isDev ? "source-map" : "",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: cssLoaders(),
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: cssLoaders("sass-loader"),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: babelLoaders(),
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: babelLoaders("@babel/preset-react"),
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./html/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      cache: false,
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd,
      },
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/favicon.ico"),
          to: PATHS.dist,
        },
      ],
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: filename("css", "css/"),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной проблемы тебе поможет [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader). Данный лоадер проходит по готовому css файлу (для этого, в случае с препроцессорами, он должен быть указан в списке перед препроцессорамми) и заменяет все места, где указан путь на тот, который есть в исходниках. Так, файлы автоматически добавляются в дерево зависимостей, заменяется их путь, а так же идет пересборка проекта, если один из этих файлов будет изменен.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/491815)

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, спасибо. Учту в следующих ответах. Этот ответ так же поправил. :)